# File Exceptions DRY principle C#

Tags: c#, error-handling, try-catch, dry

When doing a lot of different file processes in C# always the try catch block as illustrated below. Is there a way to encapsulate this in a generic class so I do not need to repeat myself DRY .

I would like to simply try catch and then handle in one class that is a flexible enough that I can add handlers to it ..

```
// The caller does not have the required permission.
Catch(UnauthorizedAccessException uae)
{

}

// sourceFileName or destFileName is a zero-length string, contains only white space, or contains one or more invalid characters as defined by InvalidPathChars.
// -or- sourceFileName or destFileName specifies a directory.
Catch(ArgumentException ae)
{

}

// sourceFileName or destFileName is null.
Catch(ArgumentNullException ane)
{

}

// The specified path, file name, or both exceed the system-defined maximum length.
Catch(PathTooLongException ptle)
{

}

// The path specified in sourceFileName or destFileName is invalid (for example, it is on an unmapped drive).
Catch(DirectoryNotFoundException dnfe)
{

}

// sourceFileName was not found.
Catch(FileNotFoundException fnfe
{

}

// destFileName exists. -or- An I/O error has occurred.
Catch(IOException ioe)
{

}

// sourceFileName or destFileName is in an invalid format.
Catch(NotSupportedException nse)
{

}
```

Comment: Create a base class with an overridable method and put it within a try catch and catch all of the above exceptions. Classes can inherit it and override the base method, exception handling will be done in base since it will bubble up.

Comment: BTW you may want to swap `ArgumentException` and `ArgumentNullException`. `ArgumentException` is a base class of `ArgumentNullException` and should intercept all the argument exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have plenty of options here. Just to mention 2 of them:

Option 1: wrapper and action.

```
public void ProcessFile()
{
    ExceptionFilters.CatchFileExceptions( () => {
        // .. do your thing
    });
}

// somewhere else
public static class ExceptionFilters
{
    public static void CatchFileExceptions(Action action)
    {
        try
        {
            action();
        }
        catch(ExceptionTypeA aex)
        {
        }
        // ... and so on
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Option 2: use exception filters
This option will actually catch every exception, unless you also use filters (C# 6+)

```
public void ProcessFile()
{
    try
    {
        // do your thing
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        if(!ProcessFileExceptions(ex))
        {
            throw; // if above hasn't handled exception rethrow
        }
    }
}

public static void ProcessFileExceptions(Exception ex)
{
    if(ex is ArgumentNullException)
    {
        throw new MyException("message", ex); // convert exception if needed
    }

    // and so on

    return true;
}
```

here you can also filter exceptions you are interested in:

```
public void ProcessFile()
{
    try
    {
        // do your thing
    }
    catch(Exception ex) when(IsFileException(ex))
    {
        if(!ProcessFileExceptions(ex))
        {
            throw; // if above hasn't converted exception rethrow
        }
    }
}

public static bool IsFileException(Exception ex)
{
    return ex is ArgumentNullException || ex is FileNotFoundException; // .. etc
}
```

Comment: In the first example - I would be wrapping the function in an exception wrapper , Is that correct ?

Comment: yes, comment `// do your thing` is inside a lambda function, that is executed as `action()` in the next function.